# Combine and sort 2 arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

This question was asked somewhere else, but I just wanted to check if what I did was applicable given the rspec circumstances:

> Write a method that takes two sorted arrays and produces the sorted array that combines both.

Restrictions:

- Do not call sort anywhere.
- Do not in any way modify the two arrays given to you.
- Do not circumvent (2) by cloning or duplicating the two arrays, only to modify the copies.

Hint: you will probably need indices into the two arrays.

```
combine_arrays([1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]) == [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Can you just combine the two arrays into a single array and then run a typical bubble sort?

```
def combine_arrays(arr1,arr2)
  final = arr1 + arr2
  sorted = true
  while sorted do
    sorted = false
    (0..final.length - 2).each do |x|
      if final[x] > final[x+1]
        final[x], final[x+1] = final[x+1], final[x]
        sorted = true
      end
    end
  end
  final
end

p combine_arrays([1,3,5],[2,4,6]) => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant which relies solely on Ruby's enumerators.  The result is short and sweet.

```
# merge two sorted arrays into a sorted combined array
def merge(a1, a2)
  [].tap do |combined|
    e1, e2 = a1.each, a2.each
    # The following three loops terminate appropriately because
    #    StopIteration acts as a break for Kernel#loop.
    # First, keep appending smaller element until one of
    #    the enumerators run out of data
    loop { combined << (e1.peek <= e2.peek ? e1 : e2).next }
    # At this point, one of these enumerators is "empty" and will
    #    break immediately. The other appends all remaining data.
    loop { combined << e1.next }
    loop { combined << e2.next }
  end
end
```

The first `loop` keeps grabbing the minimum of the two enumerator values until one of the enumerators runs out of values.  The second `loop` then appends all remaining (which may be none) values from the first array's enumerator, the third `loop` does the same for the second array's enumerator, and `tap` hands back the resulting array.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do that but you are overlooking a real gimmee - the two arrays you are given will already be sorted.

```
def combine_arrays(A1, A2)
    retVal = Array.CreateInstance(System::Int32, A1.Length + A2.Length - 1)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < A1.Length | j < A2.Length
        if i < A1.Length and self.A1(i) < self.A2(j) then
            self.retVal(i + j) = self.A1(i)
            i += 1
        else
            self.retVal(i + j) = self.A2(j)
            j += 1
        end
    end
    return retVal
end
```

Comment: Probably because I don't speak Ruby - its an online conversion from VB

Comment: @DaleM I'm a little confused. I'm still learning Ruby but your code isn't that clear. If you can, would you mind explaining? particularly your retval = ...

Comment: I do not know Ruby syntax - treat it as psedocode and write it out how you like

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the same logic as Dale M's post, but in proper ruby:

```
def combine_arrays(arr1,arr2)
  [].tap do |out|
    i1 = i2 = 0
    while i1 < arr1.size || i2 < arr2.size
      v1 = arr1[i1]
      v2 = arr2[i2]
      if v1 && (!v2 || v1 < v2)
        out << v1
        i1 += 1
      else
        out << v2
        i2 += 1
      end
    end
  end
end

combine_arrays([1,3,5], [2,4,6])
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this one:

```
def merge(arr1, arr2)
  arr2.each { |n| arr1 = insert_into_place(arr1, n) }
  arr1.empty? ? arr2 : arr1
end

def insert_into_place(array, number)
  return [] if array.empty?
  group = array.group_by { |n| n >= number }
  bigger = group[true]
  smaller = group[false]
  if bigger.nil?
    number > smaller.last ? smaller << number : smaller.unshift(number)
  else
    (smaller << number) + bigger
  end
end
```